# Problema para preencher campo de data com ASP.NET MVC, Razor

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

Estou fazendo um mini sistema de cadastro, nele tem o local de editar o cadastro de um cliente, quando clico em editar ele vem os dados nos campos para eu editar, todos os campos vem normal, menos o campo data que vem vazio.

Estava vendo que no front-end o valor vem na tag value, mas não aparece no sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller do edit:

```
// GET: Cliente/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ClienteModel clienteModel = db.Clientes.Find(id);
    if (clienteModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(clienteModel);
}

// POST: Cliente/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IdCliente,Nome,DataNascimento,Sexo,CEP,Logradouro,Complemento,Bairro,Estado,Cidade,Numero")] ClienteModel clienteModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(clienteModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

input do campo data-nascimento(estou usando razor):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "Data-Nascimento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-3", placeholder = "DD/MM/AAAA", id = "datanascimento", OnBlur = "verificarDataNascimento(datanascimento.value)" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer se estou fazendo algo de errado ?

Answer (score -1):

Descobri o problema, o campo só aceita o formato da data em yyyy-mm-dd e eu estava passando dd/mm/yyyy.